# How Tall Can Flightless Birds Plausibly Get?

Tags: biology, hard-science, anatomy, bio-mechanics, avian

These flightless birds are under strong selective pressure to be able to feed on high up conifer needles, and avoid predation from T-Rex sized predatory flightless birds. The forests the birds are evolving in are generally more open than those of our own Earth (due to being dominated by megafauna), but not as open as ones dominated by sauropods.

Importantly while these birds have many similar adaptions to sauropods, I've heard height is a much more significant limitation than total size, and that sauropods held their heads much lower most of the time than is often depicted. So with only tail feathers and not an actual tail it seems like these birds will be limited in how much their neck can extend horizontally compared to a sauropod.

*Your answer should include some calculations and/or citations about the relevant physiological constraints on tail-less avian biped height. Particularly when it comes to getting enough oxygen to their proportionally tiny brains.*

This is relevant as it seems like how high an animal can pump blood above its heart is actually fairly controversial: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sauropod_neck_posture

Comment: No calculations or anything but the only thing that my brain would allow in my head as I read this is [Therizinosaurus][1] :)


  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Therizinosaurus

Comment: @Gillgamesh Yeah I looked at different theropods before I realized how much not having a tail, and resting head position matters for comparison.

Comment: Three meter (10 ft) tall birds have [lived in the recent past](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorombe). And giraffes reach 5.7 meters (19 ft) tall, and they normally keep their heads up, so that is obviously possible.

Comment: @AlexP Absolutely! I initially had the birds giraffe sized, but I recently realized that's unlikely to be the limit on their potential height.

Comment: If you need a fleshy tail to balance, just re-evolve a tail; possibly a detachable one to sacrifice when bitten by a tyrranoraptor. Even feathers are alive, can mutate, and regrow if lost.

Comment: It sort of is. Blood is mostly water, and water is heavy. To pump blood five meters up, the heart must develop 0.5 atmospheres of pressure. I wouldn't push that mush further -- the heart is a biological pump, after all, and half an atmosphere of pressure pushes the walls of the heart chambers with *a lot* of force.

Comment: @AlexP I mean many animals have been taller than giraffes, so the limit is probably above that. Though there's enough differences that I can't just use other theropod dinosaurs as reference.

Comment: @DWKraus I suppose if you think that under these selection pressures flightless birds would evolve new tails (or another analogous counterweight structure) if it helped them reach higher you can include that in your answer

Comment: @VakusDrake I think it's entirely possible, but I'm not going to try and throw around math to prove it. HARD SCIENCE is a high threshold for a biology question. It's a soft science, generally.

Comment: your not going to fit enough guts in the body of a biped to be that large of an obligate herbivore.

Comment: @John There were certainly some quiet large bipedal herbivorous dinosaurs, so I'm not sure what you mean. I'm also not interested in maximizing size but height.

Comment: @John, oh really? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Therizinosaurus#/media/File:Therizinosaurus_size.png. That estimated body size is equivalent to that of a modern elephant, the largest obligate herbivore around.

Comment: @KeithMorrison and half the size of a T-rex and less than a third of a small sauropod like a Camarasaurus. by the time sauropods matter its too big.

Comment: related:  https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/124928/what-is-keeping-my-terror-bird-from-being-the-size-of-a-t-rex

Comment: I think you might not get what you're asking for under these circumstances. You see, giraffes only got this far because there are other sources of food for the current predators, making giraffes not as desirable. If these creatures truly are under the pressure you describe, then survival strategies which make them harder to hunt would be the way to go. Smaller creatures which can climb trees and stay on for safety would have the advantage. However, their food source is quite poor, so possibly there would be a limit to how small they can get before their digestion can't support them.

Answer (score 1):

**10 metres**

[image]

Last I saw *Walking with Dinosaurs* on the BBC the diplodocus were grazers and held their necks horizontal as you say.

[image]

But the Brachiosaurus was a browser and held its neck vertical.

[image]

Likely the diplodocus could not raise its neck this high and the brachiosaurus could not lower its neck.

The upright posture makes the brachiosaurus a 10 metre tall bird. Have the dinosaur people changed their minds in the last 20 years?

Comment: While it is true that all birds are dinosaurs, it is also true that not all dinosaurs are birds. In particular, birds are maniraptoran theropods, whereas *Diplodocus* and *Brachiosaurus* were sauropods. The sauropod and the theropod saurischian dinosaurs diverged in the late Triassic, more than 110 million years before the emergence of the birds (here considered the same thing as avialan eumaniraptorans). To put this in perspective, the big dinosaurs went extinct only 66 million years ago...

Comment: Everything about Brachiosaurus anatomy says it could absolutely lower its neck, and there is no reason to believe it could not.

Comment: @John Really? Do you know why it is portrayed so differently from the diplodocus in Walking with Dinosaurs? Is it the teeth?

Comment: @Daron because they are two very different sauropods with very different anatomy, diplodocids rear or feed so raising the neck involves raising the hole body, brachiosaurs keep all 4 feet on the ground and raise the head. walking with dinosaurs was not that scientifically accurate.

Comment: @AlexP it worth mentioning that all the things we think allowed sauropods to get so large are shared with birds, that is hollow bones and a one way air sac respiratory system.